# Set up a custom trust store that trusts LetsEncrypt in React native

Tags: android, ssl, react-native, ssl-certificate, okhttp

I need to set up a trust store that trusts LetsEncrypt in React native in order to be able to connect to my server which uses Let's encrypt Certificate.

This is an example in JAVA (https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java) but I don't know how to implement this in React native.

The problem is (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18032) that Let's encrypt is not trusted in older Android version (API < 20)